# phpMyAdmin Failure to Export

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I cannot export anything from my wamp mysql database using phpMyAdmin

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getHeader() on a non-object in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\common.inc.php on line 1067

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0008  357392  {main}( )   ..\export.php:0
2   0.0020  542080  include_once( 'C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\common.inc.php' )    ..\export.php:20
```

Any idea what is wrong?

I cannot find any reference to this specific error.

Comment: You could just download a new version of `phpMyAdmin` and put it inside your `drive:\wamp\www` folder. Just don't forget to rename the folder (like `phpMyAdmin2`), because the original phpMyAdmin path is a virtual path.

Comment: As suggested above, grab a copy (you are running 4.1.14 and the current one is 4.2.8) from [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php).

Comment: This could also be that you have ticked the 'Profiling' tick box, that worked for me